# Laravel delete user returns link with ID

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am making a 1 page CRUD application in laravel, Whenever i delete a user i just edited, I get a blank page or a 404. I suppose this happens because the link it returns is: admin/user/{id}.
I want to return the base url: admin/user
Without the {id} at the end.
Is there any way i can do this?

controller destroy code:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
       $user = User::find($id);
       $user->delete();
       return back();
    }
```

Comment: Once the record is deleted, then you can't get that record. if you want to return back then redirect on specific route. like redirect()->route('admin.user')

Comment: that worked, i appreciate it. it was so simple but my head just couldnt think of that

Comment: _**A**_ convention for such scenarios would be to redirect your user to the `index` of whatever resource they had deleted. So in your scenario the `index` route of your `User` resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the record is deleted, then you can't get that record.

If you want to return back then redirect on specific route.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->delete();
    return redirect()->route('admin.user')->with('success', 'Your success message');
}
```

also, you can display the flash message when your URL redirect on page.

Happy Coding!!!